# Get select options for an entityreference field using another field as a contextual filter?

Tags: views, entities

- I have a *Course Offerings* vocabulary where each taxonomy term is an educational course.
- Users have a multivalued *My Courses* [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field referring to the terms of the courses they're enrolled in.
- I have a custom content type ([Entityform](http://drupal.org/project/entityform)) with two more Entity Reference fields: a *Course* field and a *Student* field. The user must first select a course (a *Course Offerings* taxonomy term), and then select a student (a user).

**Here's the kicker**: I need to filter the *Student* select list options based on what the user selected in the *Course* field.

The *Course* field select options are generated by a view that returns the current user's *My Courses* field courses. After the user selects one of their courses, the *Student* field select options should be generated by a view that uses the course they chose as a contextual filter to return a list of only the users enrolled in that course.

I know how to build the view once I have the contextual filters, but I'm stumped as to how to pass the *Course* term to the view as a contextual filter. Is this possible?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

- Both the *Course* and *Student* fields are Entity Reference fields.
- Both use select-list widgets whose options are populated with views Entity Reference displays.
- The *Course* field comes before the *Student* field on the eform. The intention is that the person filling out the form will first choose the course. Then they'll choose the student from a list of students enrolled in the course they just selected.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do, but did you try making a Entity Reference display for the view, and then using that for the Entity Selection source on the form?

Comment: Yep, I've got that bit working. The trick is _I need to filter that view (Entity Reference display) to only show students enrolled in the previously selected course_. I'll add a bit more description to the question to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: looking for [same feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632851/dynamic-argument-to-enity-reference-views) and still not get answer :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kept an eye out for a module that does this since the original post, but never came up with anything. I've been using a sort of "one off" solution to do this on a case-by-case basis instead:

1. In a custom module, implement [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) for the
   form with your dynamic fields.
2. Add [#ajax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax) attributes to the first element to trigger and handle
   changes to it with AJAX. This will specify the AJAX callback handler
   and the HTML ID of the element to be replaced with the AJAX response.
3. In the ajax callback for that element, use the AJAX-submitted value
   to dynamically get the appropriate values for the second value. For
   me, this is usually a query of some sort with the submitted value as
   a filter.
4. Update the second field's form element [#options](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#options) attribute with the
   dynamic values and return the element.

Comment: I should also mention that there is limited support for this built into [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). A decent tutorial for how to use it can be found [here](http://www.topaix.org/2013/10/drupal-7-reference-field-option-limit.html).

Comment: The tutorial seems to have gone away, but it used the solution @muvasco mentions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Reference field option limit](https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit) module, it also does what you want.

> This module allows reference fields of several types to have their widgets'
>   available options limited by the values of other fields in the current
>   entity.